# Unit test for LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Tags: mysql, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, locking

If I execute this query hope I will be able to get a row lock

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.orgId = ?1")
public List<Customer> fetchCustomersByOrgId(Long orgId);
```

How I will be able to do a unit test for this?

Comment: By trying to modify any of the records that are supposed to be locked?

Comment: I think PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is almost same as SELECT FOR UPDATE when concurrent users try to update the same record before the update a lock can be obtained for this row